# Java Regular expressions search and replace

Tags: java, regex

When writing a text editor with find and replace functionality the user has the ability to search multiple times and then replace. In Java the search part is quite easy:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(userInput);
...
String line = ...
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
int from = 0;
while (from < line.length() && matcher.find(from)) {
  int start = matcher.start();
  int length = matcher.end() - start;
  // pseudo-code:
  if (askUser()) {
    return ...
  }

  from = start + 1;
}
```

But how to handle the replace of the n-th match? `Matcher` has `replaceAll` and `replaceFirst`. The first obviously will not be suitable, but for the `replaceFirst` the documentation says:

> Replaces the first subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern with the given replacement string.
>   **This method first resets this matcher.** It then scans the input sequence looking for a match of the pattern.

where the bold sentence makes me worry whether it would be suitable here. I'd need something to replace the current match with a certain pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace with the full `Matcher.replaceFirst` syntax, which includes possible references to capture groups, you can look at the source of `replaceFirst`. It calls two public methods in `Matcher`: `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`. You can call them too without first resetting the matcher and without doing a `find` call:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
matcher.appendTail(sb);
```

This results in a new Stringbuffer with the input string except that the current match is replaced by your replacement String (which can contain references to capture groups)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to replace a specific match, call `find()` multiple times and replace the matched portion using the `start()` and `end()` methods.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(stringToMatch);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(yourRegex).matcher(stringToMatch);
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { // n is the nth match you want to replace
    m.find();
}
builder.replace(m.start(), m.end(), yourReplacement);
```

Comment: I reckon, this will not handle regular expression syntax in `yourReplacement`, right?

Comment: @ThomasS. Well, you can create a replacement string with the matched groups by doing `m.group(1)` for example., which is similar to `\1`